# How do I get a transit visa for Riyadh?

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens

I hold the passport of India. I am currently based in Portugal. I will be traveling to India on a multi airline flight from Lisbon -> Riyadh -> India

I will be changing the airline in Riyadh, which means that I will take the luggage, and have to re-checkin with the second airline. For this purpose, I believe that I'll need the transit visa. Where do I have to apply the transit visa from? Is it online or is it at an embassy - and if it's an embassy, can I apply it at the Indian embassy in Portugal?

Comment: The Saudi embassy or tourism website might be fruitful places to make inquiries.

Comment: What kind of visa or residence permit do you have to stay in Portugal?

Comment: Also, what are the flights involved, on what date? Alternatively, the airlines, transit airport and arrival/departure times and terminals?

Comment: This https://www.my.gov.sa/wps/portal/snp/servicesDirectory/servicedetails/8474 might help

Answer (score 4):

If you are doing a self-transfer, you **will** need a visa

TIMATIC states :

> Saudi Arabia - Transit Visa
>
> Visa required.
>
> Visa Exemptions
>
> First-degree family members of passengers with a 'Saudi Premium
> Residency' card. TWOV (Transit Without Visa)
>
> Passengers transiting through Dammam (DMM), Jeddah (JED) or Riyadh
> (RUH) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country
> within 12 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of
> the airport and have documents required for the next destination.
>
> Only one transit stop-over in Saudi Arabia is permitted.

> They must stay in the international transit area of the airport

Since you are rechecking your bags, you are leaving the transit area and therefore need a visa

> can I apply it at the Indian embassy in Portugal

India doesn't deal with Saudi affairs. And the Saudi embassies don't seem to deal with visas.

You can apply and get information about the visa on the [Saudi Visa Platform](https://visa.mofa.gov.sa/)

Comment: As OP needs to enter the country, they are in the "destination = Saudi Arabia" case, not the "transit = Saudi Arabia" case, which actually allows visa on arrival in OP's case.

Answer (score 2):

[Timatic actually states](https://www.emirates.com/fr/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/visa-passport-information-results/?widgetheader=visa&nationality=in&destination=sa) that for **entering** Saudi Arabia (which you will need to do in order to get your bags and re-check them):

> ### Visa
>
> Visa required.
>
> #### Visa Exemptions:
>
> First-degree family members of passengers with a 'Saudi Premium Residency' card.
>
> #### Visa Issuance:
>
> E-visas can be obtained before departure at https://visa.visitsaudi.com/ . Passengers must have an e-visa confirmation.
>
> **Passengers with a tourist or business visa issued by USA, United Kingdom or a Schengen Member State traveling as tourists can obtain a visa on arrival for a maximum stay of 90 days. The visa must have been used at least once and should have an entry stamp of the issuing country. Passengers are allowed a total stay of 90 days within a period of 12 months. Visa fee must be paid by credit card.**
>
> First-degree family members of passengers with a tourist or business visa issued by USA, United Kingdom or a Schengen Member State traveling as tourists can obtain a visa on arrival for a maximum stay of 90 days. The visa must have been used at least once and should have an entry stamp of the issuing country. Passengers are allowed a total stay of 90 days within a period of 12 months. Visa fee must be paid by credit card
>
> **Passengers with a permanent residence permit issued by Portugal, traveling as tourists, can obtain visa on arrival for a maximum stay of 90 days. Visa fee must be paid by credit card.**
>
> (...)

(emphasis mine)

The [Saudi Government also states](https://www.visitsaudi.com/en/travel-regulations):

> **US, UK or Schengen (business or tourist) visas holders are eligible for the visa on arrival; the visa must be used at least once and has an entry stamp from the issuing country.**
>
> **US, UK or EU permanent residents are eligible for the visa on arrival.**

(emphasis mine)

Note that Indian citizens **cannot** apply for an e-visa through the online platform, so the only options available to you are visa on arrival, or to apply for a visa from the consulate/embassy (of Saudi Arabia, not India).

Comment: This only applies if they have a **permanent** residency permit (*CARTÃO DE RESIDÊNCIA PERMANENTE*), not if they have a standard, limited-validity residence permit (*TÍTULO DE RESIDÊNCIA*)